# Engraçado - cute/funny?

Tags: significado, português-europeu

I recently noticed that "engraçado" can mean both "cute" and/or "funny". It strikes me that this could lead to some terrible misunderstandings because, certainly in English, cute and funny are very different concepts. How do Portuguese avoid this potential confusion?

Comment: Funny has lots of meanings in English some of which are quite close to cute.

Comment: Could you give examples of how "engraçado" can mean cute? I do know it can mean "interesting"/"curious", but I don't remember "cute".

Comment: @Schilive Maybe they mean the diminutive, "engraçadinho" — though in pt-BR here you'd rather use "gracinha" for "cute", but I don't know about pt-PT.

Comment: @stafusa That's right, I forgot about graçinha.

Comment: @Lambie Glad to help — but it's not true, as you wrote, that's exclusively feminine, children of any gender, just to give an example, certainly can be called "_gracinha_", and I'd actually say also adults males.

Comment: @stafusa Se diz: Ele é uma graçinha. O adjetivo é sempre feminino. Não existe graçinh**o**. Você entendeu mal.

Comment: @Lambie Ah... de fato.

Comment: Até pensei que se pode exagerar: Esse burrinho é uma graçinha. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ele é muito **engraçado**.

Translation: He is very **funny**.

Ele é muito **bonitinho**.

Translation: He is **very cute**.

**BUT**: Ele é muito **engraçadinho**. [the diminutive]

Can be: He is very **cute**.

And pointed out by stafusa:
**gracinha** is also **cute**. [invariable, feminine]

This is for Brazil. But it's close in Portugal too.

Brazil: Houaiss online

> Que tem muita graça, **que faz rir; divertido, cômico**.
> **Com o propósito de fazer rir: vídeo super engraçado**.
> Que é espirituoso; **alegre, jovial**, engraçadinho.

Priberam:

> en·gra·ça·do
> adjectivo
>
> 1. **Gracioso, bonito, agradável**.
> 2. **Chistoso, divertido**, espirituoso.

There's quite a bit of overlap there. That said, in most contexts **cute** and **funny** are **not really the same.** Only the diminutive of engraçado can be cute, AFAIK.

"engraçado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2021, https://dicionario.priberam.org/engra%C3%A7ado [consultado em 24-03-2023].

Comment: Because the question is about pt-PT, your answer should _start_ by saying that it's for pt-BR.

Comment: WRT "engraçadinho", please note Artefacto's answer - in Portugal, it generally has a negative connotation (something like "smart-ass").

Comment: @ANeves Well, then, he should have said "the Portuguese" or "Portuguese people", because I didn't see it as about Iberian Portuguese necessarily. In Brazil, too, esse cara é um engraçadinho can also mean smart-ass. But the question was not about the inho/inha bit, was it?

Comment: I find that the tag [tag:português-europeu] makes the scope clear. Regardless, my opinion is different than yours - that "How do Portuguese avoid (...)" is more naturally interpreted as "Portuguese people" than "Portuguese-speakers".

Comment: @ANeves You are 100% right, but I forget to look at tags. Actually, though it has to be: How do **the Portuguese** avoid x. or How does Portuguese avoid x. For Brazilians and Americans due to the s, you don't need **the**, but for nationalities that don't have a plural s, you do need the the determiner: How do **the French** say this? versus: **How do Canadians say this?**

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked about European Portuguese and the other answers covers more of Brazilian Portuguese, here's my take.

*Engraçado* can indeed mean both *cute* (meaning attractive, but not in strong terms) and *funny* (as in humorous, not strange).

*Engraçadinho* can also kind of mean *funny*, but it's usually used in a negative ironic sense, as in *he thinks he's funny, but he's not*. I can also be used, of course, in a teasing, somewhat doubly ironic way, as a response when someone teases you, like when you respond "very funny". *Engraçadinho* can also be an even milder version of *cute*, though for that I'd say using the diminutive *-ito* would be better/more common: *engraçadito*.

As for how you distinguish between the two meanings -- well, you use the context. It's usually clear if you're talking about someone's physical attributes or something else.

In the same vein, by the way, *ter piada* usually means someone is funny. But it can also be a somewhat euphemistic way to say that someone is cute or even just generally interesting. *Não lhe acho piada nenhuma* can mean *I don't find his jokes funny* or *I don't like him at all*.